# Duplicate data output in wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following templates made using pods which are used in the same page. The output of the first template is right but the second template also displays the same data as the first template. I have set the where condition to their respective categories but it seems that the while loop is not resetting.

**first template section**

```php
<?php

$terms = get_terms( 'front_page', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'trekking',
            'trek_peak',
            'expedition',
            'great_himalayan_trai'
        ),
        'front_page' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 

  <div class="featured-card featured">
    <div class="featured-card__image featured-card__image--featured">
      <div class="book">
        <a href="https://khumbu-shangrila.com/booking/">
          <p>BOOK NOW</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="featured-card__unit-name">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-card__unit-stats featured-card__unit-stats--featured clearfix">
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="stat"><?php the_field('group_size')?></div>
        <div class="stat-value">Group Size</div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="stat"><?php the_field('duration'); ?></div>
        <div class="stat-value">Duration</div>
      </div>

      <div class="one-third no-border">
        <div class="stat"><?php the_field('price'); ?></div>
        <div class="stat-value">Cost</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**second section template**

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms('front_page', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
));
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'trekking',
            'trek_peak',
            'expedition',
            'great_himalayan_trai'
        ),
        'front_page' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}     
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="featured-card featured">
  <div class="featured-card__image featured-card__image--featured">
    <div class="book">
      <a href="https://khumbu-shangrila.com/booking/">
        <p>BOOK NOW</p> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
  </div>
  <div class="featured-card__unit-name">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <p class="status">Trek Confirmed</p>
      <p class="departure">Departure Date : 2018/01/12</p>
    </div>
  <div class="featured-card__unit-stats featured-card__unit-stats--featured clearfix">
    <div class="one-third">
      <div class="stat">2-10 pax</div>
        <div class="stat-value">Group Size</div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
         <div class="stat">16 Days</div>
         <div class="stat-value">Duration</div>
      </div>

      <div class="one-third no-border">
        <div class="stat">$1500</div>
        <div class="stat-value">Cost</div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  your problem comes from  the WP_Query  you need to  specify  the category  type you wish  it to display in each template so  that  i does not repeat .

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4 ) );


$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff' ) );
```

You  can read more about  it  Below

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query